# Try and store last login time for a user in database using perl script

Tags: perl

I have written a code Which tries to store the last login time for a user using perl Script and store it in a hash using dbmopen but it doesnot fetch me the updated login time :- 
My code goes as follows :-

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use DB_File;
use Time::localtime;
%last_good =();
%words = () ;
init_words();
print " What is your name ? \n";
$name=<STDIN>;
chomp($name);
 print "Hi $name , please Enter your secret password: \n" ;
 $passwd = <STDIN>;
 chomp($passwd);
 $i=1;
 while(! good_password($name,$passwd))
 {
  print " Wrong Password , Please Try Again : \n";
  $passwd=<STDIN>;
  chomp($passwd);
 }
print "assigning the last login time \n ";
dbmopen (%last_good,"lastdb",0777) || die "can't dbmopen lastdb: $!";
$last_good{$name} = localtime;   // update last login time if password correct
dbmclose (%last_good) || die "can't dbmclose lastdb: $!";
print "the last login time for :  $name is $last_good{$name} ";

sub init_words
{
 open(WORDLIST,"password.txt") || die " Can not Read the password.txt : $! \n";
 while(defined ($name = <WORDLIST>))
 {
  chomp($name);
  $name =~ s/\W.*// ;
  $name =~ tr /A-Z/a-z/ ;
  $password=<WORDLIST>;
  chomp($password);
  $words{$name}=$password;
  if(! defined $last_good{$name} )
  {
    dbmopen (%last_good,"lastdb",0777) || die "can't dbmopen lastdb: $!";
    $last_good{$name} = localtime;   // update login time for 1st login
    dbmclose (%last_good) || die "can't dbmclose lastdb: $!"; 
  }
  write;
 }
 close(WORDLIST) || die " Could not close the file : $! \n ";
}
```

what I am trying to do is update or put in database the 1st login time if its not their 
using `if(! defined $last_good{$name} )` and then in case its already defined when second time I run the prog I want it toread from database and not try and again create the same again. But when I try and print `$last_good{$name} = localtime;` after first assignment it doesnt print the login `localtime` but it says it to be undefined.

Comment: Is `good_password` also making `$name` lowercase? Also, I don't understand what you try to accomplish with `$name =~ s/\W.*//`. Try to dump `%last_good` with something like `Data::Dumper` to verify that it looks like you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just that you're calling `dbmclose` before trying to print the value. So of course the hash is untied.